# Google Adwords Api .Net RelatedToQuerySearchParameter

Tags: .net, api, google-ads-api

I have atupid question but it is not clear to me: 
Is the RelatedToQuerySearchParameter class (that Except a list of string keywords) treat the keywords string as Exact Match?